# Importar datos a una hoja de google a traves de =IMPORTHTML

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Quiero importar datos cada minuto y que esto se haga de forma automatica. Para ello tomo datos de la pagina que tengo en la celda A1 y tomo el dato en forma de "table" en A2, y lo represento en A3. A esto le sumo un activador de la hoja de google, para que se repita cada minuto.

Consigo que se ejecute una vez, despues al tener la hoja rellena con los datos, nos lo vuelve a actualizar, sin embargo si borro los datos al cabo del minuto se vuelven a rellenar con los dastos importados y actualizados.

Como consigo que estos se vayan renovando cada minuto.

```
function getHTMLData() { 
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TR"); 
  var queryString = Math.random(); 
  var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML(A1;A2)';

    sheetName.getRange("A3").setValue(cellFunction); 

}
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cual es el problema exactamente. Por otra parte, ¿revisaste el estado de las `Ejecuciones` en el menú lateral de GAS (nueva versión)?. Allí te dirá si el activador está funcionando, si hay errores, etc. En la opción `Activadores` podrás ver también si tu activador está registrado. Y verificar las Ejecuciones con éxito y las Ejecuciones fallidas.

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios A.Cedano. Las ejecuciones son correctas, cada 1 minuto tengo 1 ejecución. El activador esta activo y no reporta ningún mensaje de error. Para que me importe los datos de forma correcta, la hoja debe de estar en blanco. Por ejemplo, inicio el proceso con la hoja en blanco y se ejecuta de forma correcta la secuencia de importación de datos, pero tras esa primera importación, ya no me vuelve a importar los datos, y la hoja se queda con los datos sin actualizar.

Comment: Sin ver el código y tener claro el contexto es difícil poder ayudarte. Por ejemplo, ¿dónde se define la condición de que para que funcione la hoja debe estar en blanco y por qué debe ser así y si debe ser así, de que modo limpias la hoja?